# How to update property bags for classic and modern sites in Sharepoint Online using C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

```
public interface ISiteMetadataField
{
    string Name { get; set; }

    string Value { get; set; }               
}

public class SiteMetadataField : ISiteMetadataField
{
    private string _name;
    private string _Value;


    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
    public string Value
    {
        get { return _Value; }
        set { _Value = value; }
    }

}

private Web UpdateTextField(Web web, ISiteMetadataField siteMetaDataItem)
{
 web.SetPropertyBagValue(siteMetaDataItem.Name, 
 Convert.ToString(siteMetaDataItem.Value)); 
 return web;
}
```

I am trying to update the property bag for the classic and modern site as per the article below:-
https://asishpadhy.com/2018/04/23/how-to-set-property-bag-values-in-sharepoint-modern-sites-using-sharepoint-online-net-csom/

I am getting the below error when i am trying to update:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.'

I have already checked that I have the required permissions as I am able to update the values Chrome SP Dev Tools extension. But when I am doing the same via code, I am getting the error. Please guide as I am new to SharePoint.

Comment: did you run the powershell script first before executing the code ?

Comment: No, which powershell script do we need to run?

Comment: Its mentioned in the blog `Set-SPOsite -Url "https://sitecollectionurl"  -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0`

Comment: Actually I need to do it using the C# code without using powershell.  I was referring to the resolution in the blog :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the `IsNoScript` setting by setting the DenyAddAndCustomizePages to disabled first.

So, to do that using CSOM, you can use the below method:

```
var tenant = new Tenant(clientContext);
var siteProperties = tenant.GetSitePropertiesByUrl("https://<your-sitecollection-url>", true);
tenant.Context.Load(siteProperties);
tenant.Context.ExecuteQuery();

siteProperties.DenyAddAndCustomizePages = DenyAddAndCustomizePagesStatus.Disabled;
var operation = siteProperties.Update();
tenant.Context.Load(operation, i => i.IsComplete, i => i.PollingInterval);
tenant.Context.ExecuteQuery();

// this is necessary, because the setting is not immediately reflected after ExecuteQuery
while (!operation.IsComplete)
{
    Thread.Sleep(operation.PollingInterval);
    operation.RefreshLoad();
    if (!operation.IsComplete)
    {
        try
        {
            tenant.Context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
        catch (WebException webEx)
        {
            // catch the error, something went wrong
        }
    }
}
```

Once the above code is executed for your site collection, you should run your `UpdateTextField` method and it will update property bag.

**Do note:** - this code requires SharePoint tenant admin rights, it will not work with Site collection admin rights.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! One question: how did you grant the SharePoint tenant admin rights? I am using an Azure app principal, and I granted the SharePoint Administrator right to it to no avail.